# how to access a row of whole datatable at the same time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I use the DataTables jQuery plugin. In that DataTable I have created a check box in the header and every column has a check box too.

That DataTable has a few pages. What I need is when I check the header checkbox then all checkboxes should be checked in all the pages of the DataTable.

I have to access the rows of all pages at a same time.

I tried this

```
if($('#selectAll').is(':checked')){
    $(nRow).find(':input[name=group_select_components]').iCheck('check');
}
```

I can check the checkboxes when I will click the paginate. But I want to access a row of the dataTable at the same time..

Comment: What do you mean by at same time ?

Comment: when i will check the header checkbox the other checkboxes(in the page 1,2,..)will be checked automatically  in the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code!!

```
if($('#selectAll').is(':checked')){
    var table = $('#yourTableId').DataTable();
    var cells = table
        .cells( ":checkbox" )
        .nodes();
    $(cells).iCheck('check');
}
```

or this

```
if($('#selectAll').is(':checked')){
    var table = $('#yourTableId').DataTable();
    $(':checkbox', table.rows().nodes()).iCheck('check');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by assigning the same class for all check boxes. So when you click to select all, all boxes will be checked.

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selecctall').click(function(event) {  //click event
        if(this.checked) { // Check if the box is checked
            $('.checkbox').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox"               
            });
        }else{
            $('.checkbox').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox"                       
            });         
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if your table has an id or class.

```
if($('#selectAll').is(':checked'))
 $("#YourTableId tr td:first-child").each(function(){$(this).find(':input[name=group_select_components]').iCheck('check')});
```

Here it will find checkboxes in `first td` if your checkboxes are in another `td` you can give `index` of that td by using `.eq()`. This will only loop on specific `tds`.

Or If you don't want to set index of td than you can simply loop through rows

```
if($('#selectAll').is(':checked'))
 $("YourTableId tr").each(function(){$(this).find(':input[name=group_select_components]').iCheck('check')})
```